# How can I align the image and the h1 header ajadecently?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have problems with trying to align the image and the h1 tag together on one line. I tried display: inline and inline-block they didn't work and only made the container of the two. I added the width to 100% on the section and still nothing. Float doesn't work either and if it did, it screws up the alignment of the page. What am I doing wrong? Sometimes it's hard to understand why it doesn't work as intended and need some help.

HTML

```
<section>
    <img id="me" src="assets/img/pose1.jpg" alt="A photo of me." />
    <h1>FOLLOW ME ON...</h1>
</section>
```

CSS

```
section{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
}
h1{
    position:relative; /*position wherever desired on the page*/
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:40px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#FFB405;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add `display: inline-block;` to your `h1` properties, as I've done [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HMN2T/).

Comment: the full code doesn't do the change, maybe the problem lies else where, check my js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TheAmazingKnight/bkmyv/

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Where are you trying to place your image? Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/bkmyv/6/) what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
h1{
position:relative; /*position wherever desired on the page*/
top:0;
bottom:0;
right:0;
left:0;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:40px;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#FFB405;
 display: inline-block; 
}
```

Comment: the full code doesn't do the change, maybe the problem lies else where, check my js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TheAmazingKnight/bkmyv/

Answer (score 0):

You have some CSS conflicts on `h1`...

This should work

```
section {
    display: block;
}
h1 {
    position:relative; /*position wherever desired on the page*/
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:40px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#FFB405;
}
section img { 
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: the full code doesn't do the change, maybe the problem lies else where, check my js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TheAmazingKnight/bkmyv/

Comment: @TheAmazingKnight The image (#me) wasn't with inline-block display. http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/bkmyv/7/ See this fiddle